# Where would the questions from this site go, if it were closed?

Tags: discussion

Many times when a beta site gets shutdown its questions are migrated to other SE sites accordingly.  I remember (I think) of an Arduino site a few years ago that was shut down, and the questions were migrated to a number of other sites such as programming, physics, and mostly electrical engineering.

I can't think of any sites that the questions from this Aviation beta would be able to transfer to if it were to close.

So, if this site doesn't "make it" will its content just die out?

Comment: from the duplicate question (that **you** asked): `And if it doesn't make it what's going to happen to all these questions?`

Answer (score 13):

As Lnafziger said, there's no danger of that happening, so it doesn't really matter. We've actually been continuing to grow this year.

If a site is closed, a data dump of its questions and answers are made available on Area 51. For example, see the [Artificial Intelligence](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/57719/artificial-intelligence) site which didn't work out.

Questions are only migrated when there is a very clear and large overlap with another site. It's very rare for that to happen, and certainly wouldn't be the case with this site.

Answer (score 5):

With the level of activity that we have here, we are in no danger of the site being shut down, so the point is moot!

If things were different and the site wasn't being used, then it would be deleted.  See [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60895/what-happens-when-a-site-fails-to-meet-the-beta-requirements) and the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) (question #3) for more details.

Comment: Out of interest, what is (roughly) the level of activity required? We seem to be at roughly 6-8 questions a day, with plenty of answers and discussion: in fact, a very high rate of answered questions... but is there a guideline?